# How can I invert (swap) the case of each letter in a string?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and am working on this exercise:

> Create a function that will return another string similar to the input string, but with its case inverted. For example, input of "Mr. Ed" will result in "mR. eD" as the output string.

My code is:

```
name = 'Mr.Ed'
name_list = []

for i in name:
    if i.isupper():
        name_list.append(i.lower())
    elif i.islower():
        name_list.append(i.upper())
    else:
        name_list.append(i)

    print(''.join(name_list))
```

Is there a simpler or more direct way to solve it?

Comment: The code is perfectly clear and straight forward. You could use a list comprehension instead of `append` perhaps.

Comment: You mean better as in faster or as in smaller

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine.
You don't need three branches though, because `str.upper()` will return str when upper is not applicable anyway.

With generator expressions, this can be shortened to:

```
>>> name = 'Mr.Ed'
>>> ''.join(c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in name)
'mR.eD'
```

Answer (score 118):

You can do that with `name.swapcase()`. Look up the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) (or see [the older docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.swapcase) for legacy Python 2).

Answer (score 16):

Simply use the swapcase() method:

```
name = "Mr.Ed"
print(name.swapcase())
```

Output: mR.eD

*Explanation:*

The method swapcase() returns a copy of the string in which all the case-based characters have had their case swapped.

Answer (score 4):

In python, an inbuilt function swapcase() is present which automatically converts the case of each and every letter. Even after entering the mixture of lowercase and uppercase letters it will handle it properly and return the answer as expected.

Here is my code:

```
str1 = input("enter str= ")
res = str1.swapcase()
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name='Mr.Ed'
print(name.swapcase())
```

Comment: This has already been posted multiple times. ([1](/a/26386127/4518341), [2](/a/47050816/4518341), [3](/a/55255469/4518341)) Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: Alright!! Noted!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/suryashekhawat/pythonExamples/blob/master/string_toggle.py

```
    def toggle(mystr):
        arr = []
        for char in mystr:
            if char.upper() != char:
                char=char.upper()
                arr.append(char)
            else:
                char=char.lower()
                arr.append(char)
        return ''.join(map(str,arr))
    user_input = raw_input()
    output = toggle(user_input)
    print output
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

The following program is for toggle case

```
name = input()
for i in name:
    if i.isupper():
        print(i.lower(), end='')
    else:
        print(i.upper(), end='')
```

Comment: The quality of this answer is really quite low. Obviously the formatting could be improved. Furthermore, for an answer to be useful, one needs to comment and explain. Finally I don't really see a difference with other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: "Moved" the answer from [[SO]: Python: Replace lower case to upper, and vice versa, simultaneously via ReGex lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76068146/4788546) (so more people can benefit out of it).

This is more like an exercise: I wanted to do a comparison between different variants (and apparently *ReggaExp* tends to be slower than string manipulations - and (as expected) *swapcase* is waaay faster than anything else).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import string
import sys
import timeit


def swap_case_re(s):
    return re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)|([a-z]+)", lambda arg: arg.group(1).lower() if arg.group(1) else arg.group(2).upper(), s)


def swap_case_s0(s):
    return "".join(c.lower() if "A" <= c <= "Z" else c.upper() if "a" <= c <= "z" else c for c in s)


def swap_case_s1(s):
    return s.swapcase()


def swap_case_s2(s):
    return "".join(chr(c + 0x20 if 0x41 <= c <= 0x5A else c - 0x20 if 0x61 <= c <= 0x7A else c) for c in s.encode())


def swap_case_s3(s):
    return "".join(c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in s)


def swap_case_s4(s, tbl="".maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)):
    return s.translate(tbl)


FUCS = (
    swap_case_re,
    swap_case_s0,
    swap_case_s1,
    swap_case_s2,
    swap_case_s3,
    swap_case_s4,
)


def test_acc():
    print("Test accuracy:")
    for s in ("Www.GooGle.com",):
        for func in FUCS:
            print("{:s}({:s}): {:s}".format(func.__name__, s, func(s)))


def test_perf(count=1000000):
    print("\nTest performance:")
    for func in FUCS:
        print("{:s}: {:.3f}".format(func.__name__, timeit.timeit(lambda: func("Www.GooGle.com"), number=count)))


def main(*argv):
    test_acc()
    test_perf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output** (*Win*):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076068146]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Test accuracy:
> swap_case_re(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
> swap_case_s0(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
> swap_case_s1(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
> swap_case_s2(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
> swap_case_s3(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
> swap_case_s4(Www.GooGle.com): wWW.gOOgLE.COM
>
> Test performance:
> swap_case_re: 5.039
> swap_case_s0: 3.607
> swap_case_s1: 0.315
> swap_case_s2: 3.034
> swap_case_s3: 2.700
> swap_case_s4: 0.535
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`changeCase` `lambda` method reverses the case of `string` if the character is alpha then perform `(chr(ord(char)^32)` which flips the case of a alphabet. `''.join([])`  converts the list to a `string`.

- [ord](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ord-function-python/) returns an `Unicode` code representing a `character`.
- [chr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chr-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20chr()%20method%20returns,code%20point%20is%20an%20integer.&text=The%20chr()%20method%20takes,point%20is%20num%2C%20an%20integer.) converts an `integer` to a `character`.

### main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10
changeCase = lambda x: ''.join([(chr(ord(v)^32) if 65 <= ord(v) <= 90 or 97 <= ord(v) <= 122 else v) for v in x])

print(changeCase("Dev Parzival"))
print(changeCase("Hello World!"))
print(changeCase("Haÿ"))
```

### Output:

```
$ chmod +x main.py
$ ./main.py
dEV pARZIVAL
hELLO wORLD!
hAÿ
```

Comment: Doesn't work for all non-ASCII characters, for example: `"Haÿ"` -> `"hAß"`. (Should be `"hAŸ"`)

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for pointing out the bug because of non-ASCII characters. I might haven't realized it. Now it supports non-ASCII characters as well.

Comment: Now it doesn't do non-ASCII characters at all... Like I said, the output should be `"hAŸ"`, with a capital `Ÿ`. Anyway, I don't see any reason to try to roll your own solution when you could just use `str.swapcase()`, like others have answered.