# [Python]How to distinguish same letters in string using loops

Tags: python

I want program to change all lower letters to upper and vice versa
but if there is same letters it only takes first eg. "Aa" it should change it to "aA", but it gives me "AA" instead "aA", I think because it changes always first letter

```
S = input()
for item in S:
    if item.islower():
        S = S.replace(item, item.upper())
    elif item.isupper():
        S = S.replace(item, item.lower())
print(S)
```

Comment: Also see: [**better way to invert case of string**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26385823/1164465)

Comment: The issue is `str.islower()` returns true only if all the characters in the string are lowercase, try using it on the actual characters in the underlying string instead:
https://repl.it/repls/HumiliatingThirstyVendor#main.py

Comment: I know that it is possible to do that another way, but my point is to change cases of existing string without creating another on or another tab

Answer (score 0):

U don't need to call the replace method. Instead let ur code look like this.
for item in s:
if item.islower():
print(item.upper() end='')
else:
print (item.lower())

Comment: but then it prints every letter in new line, I did the program in other way, but i want to make it to change the content of base string, it's my goal for learning

Comment: pls, don't add a space between the end kwarg, just the quote